# Is there a bike less prone to having the chain fall off?

Tags: chain

So my biggest frustration with my bike is that because of weather, abuse and bumpy trails the chains eventually come off.

Unfortunately this often happens in the least ideal situation.

Is there a term for a bike that won't have this problem?  I found on this site chainless bikes(not common) but again this doesn't seem to solve this issue necessarily.  I would assume a bike with no speeds could have a thicker less prone to falling off chain but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please provide more details about what you mean by "the chains come off"? Do you mean it drops off the chainrings (the big cogs by the pedals)? So you have to stop and hitch it back on? If so, that's probably a front derailleur limit screw adjustment issue. Or do you mean your chain literally snaps and you have to walk your bike back out of the trails and go to a bike shop for a new chain or chain repair?

Comment: @SSilk it has yet to snap.  Yes it drops off.  I end up walking my bike or alternatively getting my hands dirty.  I do believe this is caused from bike abuse.  So a bike that allows maximum abuse would be ideal.

Comment: How old is the bike? What drivetrain do you have? Number of speeds? Tripple, double?

Comment: @William Per my comment, and Argenti's answer below, there are a lot of possible explanations and fixes, but your cheapest easiest thing to check would be to make sure your FD limit screws are set as tight as they can go while still allowing you to get to your two outermost chainrings. If you're still dropping after that, you can investigate the other options like replacing chain/casette/chainrings or moving to a 1x drivetrain or something more exotic.

Comment: You might want to rethink your title - you're not destroying anything

Comment: VTC - nothing is indestructable so this is an impossible question. Cycles value low weight which is the opposite of durable.

Comment: @Criggie if you would like to close it that is fine but this has helped answer the intent of my question.  1) less common - belt driven and shaft driven don't have the chain fall off 2) more common - single speed or fixie bikes or IGH don't have a derailleur and therefore there is no chain to fall off unless it breaks

Comment: Have you always had this problem, or does it seem to be getting worse?  Consider that your chain and cogs may be worn and in need of replacement.  I've found that a worn front cog is especially likely to cause the chain to jump off (though wear anywhere in the drive train can cause trouble).

Comment: @William doing great - the question is now much better.  I have retracted my vote.

Comment: @Criggie the bike is much older then me so it has likely existed like since I have been born.  It has done this since I have risen it.

Answer (score 7):

So you question is actually: is there a drive train system that I can abuse as much as I like and it will never fail? The general answer to that is *no*, there is not.

There are systems that require much less maintenance than a traditional derailleur and chain. There are belt drive systems with internal gears, either at the bottom bracket location or in the rear hub. However these systems are relatively heavy, can be more fragile and have greater losses than an unworn, clean derailleur setup. Consequently they appear on city and commuter bikes.

There are systems employed on mountain bikes to retain the chain. '1x' systems with a single chainring and a clutch rear derailleur. There are also many chain guide products available.

Newer derailleur drivetrain designed are also just generally much better at resisting chain suck and dropping the chain.

If you hate dropping your chain, invest some time and money in getting your drive-train set up properly. Your chain and sprockets are probably worn and your derailleur limit settings may be out.

Also, you can add a mechanic's disposable nitrile glove or two to your trail riding tool kit.

Update: I noticed the question does not actually state the bike has a derailleur. If it's a single speed or hub geared bike and dropping the chain, the chain tension must be far too loose.

Comment: So I had the bike serviced and it is still happening.  Would a fixed gear bike imply the Chain would have to break to fall off?

Comment: If you have an older bike, the drivetrain may just be prone to dropping the chain. Newer designs are more resistant to this. Your rear derailleur tension springs may also have weakened. A single speed *cannot* drop the chain as there is not enough slack for it to come off the sprockets (if it's properly adjusted).

Comment: Servicing doesn't generally involve checking the FD limit screws unless the chainrings/bottom bracket are being worked on anyway -- there should be no need.  Some drivetrains are hard to get both shifting nicely and not dropping.  Dropping is *much* more likely if you're running in small cogs front and rear, because the chain has so much slack in it

Comment: Maybe you need a different kind of bike rather than just a different chain. Traditional Dutch bikes (chain inside a cover) almost never suffer from chain problems.

Comment: @Willeke that sounds like a great idea.  What are the guards called?  It would prevent my pants from getting into the chain and solve 2 problems possibly.

Comment: A chain case, see this site (he has links to his own bike parts shop, so the site is a bit commercial.) http://www.aviewfromthecyclepath.com/2009/01/anatomy-of-reliable-everyday-bicycle.html

Comment: Dutch bikes typically have hub gears and hence single sprocket. Don’t think I’ve ever seen a chain guard for a derailleur equipped bike.

Comment: There are chain guards for bikes with front derailleurs. They're not full chain cases but will protect your trousers from grease, and to some extent keep the chain in (though it should be set up perfectly first). I bought two from a online shop called something like "Dutch bike bits", though on one bike I just couldn't get it to fit

Answer (score 2):

There were occasional shaft-driven bikes.

[image: from http://www.oldbike.eu/chainless/]

Much more info at http://www.oldbike.eu/chainless/ but in short they were seen most before the invention of roller chain.

Roller chain has high efficiency compared to non-roller chain, and this was enough to make other solutions less popular.

Shaft bikes might still suit environments where its very damp, like underground mines.

The main downsides are

- Require singlespeed/fixed gear, OR an internally geared hub.
- Rear wheel changes are significantly more difficult.
- Small diametre shafts mean excessive levels of torque, so the gearboxes at either end have to be solid and robust, which means heavy.
- Both gearboxes will be turning the force through about a right angle, so they will be complex shapes internally.  Both will likely be running in an oil-bath on older bikes, or "greased for life" on newer bike styles.
- Uncommon, so parts will be near-impossible to find.

Here's a modern shaft BMX  https://www.trademe.co.nz/1621164443

[image: https://trademe.tmcdn.co.nz/photoserver/full/746727746.jpg]
[image: https://trademe.tmcdn.co.nz/photoserver/plusw/746727900.jpg]
[image: https://trademe.tmcdn.co.nz/photoserver/plusw/746727900.jpg]

---

Addendum - here's another drive system that is technically shaft drive, but the three shafts are all parallel rather than the middle one being rotated.

[image: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0050/4252/files/21730300_1024x1024.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

First I’d like to point out that this shouldn’t happen on a modern, quality, properly set up derailleur drivetrain.

If you are still searching for a permanent, (almost) completely trouble free solution you should probably get an **internal gear hub or single speed**. With a properly tensioned chain or a chain tensioner those last a long time without any issues and minimal maintenance requirements. The disadvantages of a single speed are obviously that you only have one gear. The disadvantages of an internal gear hub is a slightly reduced efficiency and reduced range of gears compared to a derailleur drivetrain.

For example the cheap Shimano Nexus/Inter 8 only has 8 gears with a total range of 306%. So you can go from about 12.7km/h to 39km/h (at a cadence of 90rpm). Completely sufficient for a flat area, less so for a hilly/very windy area. Even the expensive Rohloff Speedhub only has 14 gears for a total range of 526% (you can go from approximately 9km/h to 50km/h).

I don’t think you need exotic/expensive solutions such as a shaft drive or belt drive. They usually use internal gear hubs as well and a chain is not necessarily a bad thing. Internal gear hubs with chains are a proven product and often found on commuting and city bikes because of their reliability.